# Optimize loading and searching from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have code that searching for high, medium and low matches by name, postcode and city. It's working well but slow on big amount of comparing data.

Here is code of it

```
public abstract class GenericScoreSupplierComparisonService<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, ISupplierComparisonWithScore
{
    private readonly ILogger<GenericScoreSupplierComparisonService<TEntity>> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _services;
    private readonly DataPipelineDbContext _dataPipelineDbContext;


    public GenericScoreSupplierComparisonService(ILogger<GenericScoreSupplierComparisonService<TEntity>> logger,
        IServiceProvider services, DataPipelineDbContext dataPipelineDbContext)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _services = services;
        _dataPipelineDbContext = dataPipelineDbContext;
    }


    protected MatchingScoreOutput FindMatch(string name, string postalCode, string city)
    {
        try
        {
            string comparisonName = ComparablePropsHelper.GetComparableCompanyName(name);
            string comparisonPostalCode = ComparablePropsHelper.GetComparablePostalCode(postalCode);
            string comparisonCity = ComparablePropsHelper.GetComparableCompanyName(city);


            var highestMatched = _dataPipelineDbContext.JobSuppliers.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                x.SupplierNameNormalized == comparisonName && x.City == comparisonCity &&
                x.PostalCodeClean == comparisonPostalCode);

            var hightMatched = _dataPipelineDbContext.JobSuppliers.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                x.SupplierNameNormalized == comparisonName && x.City == comparisonCity);

            var mediumMatched = _dataPipelineDbContext.JobSuppliers.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                x.SupplierNameNormalized.Contains(comparisonName) && x.City == comparisonCity);

            var lowMatсhed = _dataPipelineDbContext.JobSuppliers.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                x.SupplierNameNormalized.Contains(comparisonName));

            if (highestMatched != null)
            {
                return new MatchingScoreOutput
                {
                    MatchFound = true,
                    Confidence = MatchConfidence.HIGH,
                    MatchedEntity = highestMatched,
                    Score = 90
                };
            }

            if (hightMatched != null)
            {
                return new MatchingScoreOutput
                {
                    MatchFound = true,
                    Confidence = MatchConfidence.HIGH,
                    MatchedEntity = hightMatched,
                    Score = 80
                };
            }

            if (mediumMatched != null)
            {
                return new MatchingScoreOutput
                {
                    MatchFound = true,
                    Confidence = MatchConfidence.MEDIUM,
                    MatchedEntity = mediumMatched,
                    Score = 60
                };
            }

            if (lowMatсhed != null)
            {
                return new MatchingScoreOutput
                {
                    MatchFound = true,
                    Confidence = MatchConfidence.LOW,
                    MatchedEntity = mediumMatched,
                    Score = 40
                };
            }

            return new MatchingScoreOutput {MatchFound = false, Confidence = MatchConfidence.UNMATCHED,};
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex,
                $"{nameof(GenericScoreSupplierComparisonService<TEntity>)}: Exception occurred. Message: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Problem that I can call this method for list of 200-300 items and `JobSuppliers` table has 30k items  and this whole process is taking much time. Any advice how I can speed up this `FindMatch` method.

Comment: Hard to tell in detail without more info on indexes etc. But - you run four queries and then decide which to return. If your first query - the highest match - gets a result, then just return that. If not try the next highest, and do the same with each query.

Comment: @stuartd but I don’t want only highest match, I want also medium and low matches

Comment: You’re only returning one value though? ```if (highestMatched != null)  {  return new MatchingScoreOutput…```

Comment: That line could me moved to just below when the highest matched query runs. If it hasn’t returned a result - is null, in other words - then try the next query. If that returns a result, return that. If not, keep running queries in the same way until you get to the end and decide there are no matches.

Comment: How is the table indexed? 30k rows is pretty small for most RDBMSes, so i can only assume you dont have proper indexes on the table.

Comment: (I would write up an example but AFK)

Comment: IMHO turn those comparisons into a score, eg `.Select(x => new { x, Score = (x.City == comparisonCity ? 8 : 0) + ( ... ? 4 : 0) + ...}` , then `.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).Take(<N>)`.

Comment: @stuartd I return `highestMatched` if found, then `hightMatched` if found, etc.